# Websphere Commerce Checkout Flow with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, checkout, websphere-commerce, wcs

I'm having problems with the simulation of the checkout flow with Jmeter. I believe there is a problem with the session management. I have already added a cookie manager in order to use the wcs cookies trough my testing plan. Has anybody ever done this? Please help me.

I also checked the SystemOut.log, and i found this exceptions(I don't have the exact text but it's similar to:

The user #### does not have the authority to run this command

or

The user does not have the authority to run this command

This happens with OrderItemUpdateCmd and OrderProcessCmd.

Please help me, thanks in advace.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime this error occurs if we haven't run the acpload after adding new controller commands. Are you getting this error with the Out of Box WCS commands or the new controller commands added.